# Evaluating logarithm of expression, given logarithms of variables

Tags: math, optimization, logarithm, expression-evaluation, natural-logarithm

I have to programmatically determine the value of the expression:

```
 S = log(x1y1 + x2y2 + x3y3 ...)
```

Using only the values of:

```
lxi = log(xi)
lyi = log(yi)
```

Calculating anti-logs of each of *lx<sub>i</sub>* and *ly<sub>i</sub>* would probably be impractical and is not desired ...

Is there any way this evaluation can be broken down into a **simple summation?**

**EDIT**

I saw a C function somewhere that does the computation in a simple summation:

```
double log_add(double lx, double ly)
{
   double temp,diff,z;

   if (lx<ly) {
      temp = lx; lx = ly; ly = temp;
   }
   diff = ly-lx;
   z = exp(diff);
   return lx+log(1.0+z);
}
```

The return values are added for each pair of values, and this seems to be giving the correct answer. But I'm not able to figure out how and why it's working!

Comment: It is impossible. You have to get the anti-logs. Besides, its not that hard to get the anti-logs, you just have to do 10^(log(xi))

Comment: What @sshashank124 said, but if the log is natural log, use e instead of 10.

Comment: That `log_add` is a clever way to do *one* anti-log instead of *two*. We can walk you through it if you like.

Comment: @Beta Yes please, that'd be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct way is to perform two exponentiations:

ln(x+y) = ln(e<sup>ln(x)</sup> + e<sup>ln(y)</sup>)

The `log_add` function uses a slightly different approach to get the same result with only *one*:

ln(x+y) = ln((x+y)x/x)
= ln((x+y)/x) + ln(x)
= ln(1 + y/x) + ln(x)
= ln(1 + e<sup>ln(y/x)</sup>) + ln(x)
= ln(1 + e<sup>ln(y)-ln(x)</sup>) + ln(x)

Comment: Neat trick. I wonder whether this would be faster then the original - we still need to make a `log()` call, and an extra conditional to evaluate. What do you think?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817491/c-exp-vs-log-which-is-faster) hints that `log()` might be faster